# Technique for maximising the product/sum of multiple single variable functions given a linear constraint (general problem)

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Today we used a techique in our optimisation class for which I am wondering if it can be generalised. In our case we had three functions and wanted to maximise their sum. The problem looked like this:
Maximise the function $$ 2x_1^2 + 2x_2 + 4x_3 - x_3^2$$ given the contraints $$2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 4$$ $$ x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0, x_3 \ge 0.$$

We contructed a recursive method for solving the problem. Let $f_2(x) = 2x$, so we identify $f_2(x)$ with the $x_2$ portion of our multivariable function. We the let $f_1(x) = max(2y^2 + f_2(x-2y) \mid 0 \le y \le \frac{x}{2})$. And finally we let $f_3(x) = max(f_1(x-z) + 4z-z^2 \mid 0 \le z \le x)$. The optimum is achieved at $f_3(4)$. First we calculate the function $f_1(x) = 2x$ and finally we calculate the optimum of our function $f_3(x) = max(2(x-z) + 4z-z^2 \mid 0 \le z \le x)$ by taking its derivative. We find the optimum at $z = 1$ and finally get the values
$x_1 = 0, x_2 = 3, x_3 = 1$.

Suppose we have $n$ functions $f_1(x_1), f_2(x_2)...f_n(x_n) \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Given a linear constraint in the form of $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... +a_nx_n \leq b$ where $a_1, a_2, ...a_n, b \in \mathbb{R}$ we want to maximise/minimise either the product $f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2)\cdots f_n(x_n)$ or the sum $f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+... +f_n(x_n)$. My question is: Can we use the same technique for solving this more genereal version of the problem, if so, why? If not, what would some additional constraints be?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, the answer was indeed x = (0, 3, 1).

Answer (score 1):

The problem of optimizing a quadratic function subject to linear constraints is called [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming).  Your example with a separable quadratic function of nonnegative variables and a single linear constraint with positive coefficients can be solved via [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).  So can your generalization to optimization of a separable function.  When the variables are required to take integer variables, this is known as a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), with the most common variant using linear functions $f_i$.

Comment: And what would the dynamic programming technique look like? Would you just repeat the process from the example?

Comment: You can find a lot of ideas in this publication https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reports/2006/R352.pdf